# Play sound when typing in EditText in android application

Tags: java, android, audio, android-edittext

Hi i am making an android application.
I want to play a default sound effect when i am typing in an EditText field.
Any ideas how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [textwatcher](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) for that purpose

```
 youredittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
          MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.yourmp3); // add mp3 file 
          mp.start();
            }
        });
```

**Note : add yourmp3 in `res->raw` folder**

Comment: It just need to release the mp every time to prevent fast clicking error

Comment: yes you can search about mediaplayer for that . they will have some methods that will appropriate .

Comment: like you can create only one instance globally for mediaplayer and start it in beforetextchange() and end it in aftertextchange() . this is just a hint i know you will come up with good idea.

Comment: MediaPlayer is used for long music or songs, if you need to put a sound effect that is no longer than 5 seconds for like every press it is more recommended to use the SoundPool class, the MediaPlayer is more suitable for the long background music like in games.
Ps:SoundPool limit is 1M or it will fails :)